# How do i change polymer's paper-input-decorator label color and underline in javascript?

Tags: polymer

This is inside my jsp file:

```
<paper-input-decorator  floatingLabel label="Username" Id="textfield" >
    <input type="text" name="user" Id="user">
</paper-input-decorator>

<paper-input-decorator floatingLabel label="Password">
    <input type="password" name="pass" Id="pass">  
</paper-input-decorator><br>
```

And this is my function inside the javascript file(triggered by a paper button)

```
function autenticate(){

    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var user1= document.getElementById("user");


    var passw = document.getElementById("pass").value;  
    var passw1 = document.getElementById("pass");

    if(user.length<1){

    }else{ 
        document.login.submit(); 
    }
```

I want to color in red the label and underline of the user(paper input decorator)  if user.length is <1. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The hard way would be the create a CSS class and assign it as followed:

**CSS**

```
paper-input-decorator.red-label /deep/ .label-text {
 color:red;
}
```

**JS**

```
var authenticate = function() {
 var user = document.getElementById("user");

 if(user.value.length < 1) {
  user.parentNode.classList.add("red-label");
 } else {
  user.parentNode.classList.remove("red-label");
 }
}
```

The easy way would be just to use the autovalidation option of the paper-input, e..g:

```
<paper-input-decorator label="required" floatinglabel error="input is required!" autovalidate layout vertical class="invalid">
      <input is="core-input" required="" placeholder="required>
    </paper-input-decorator>
```

Comment: Note: This answer is for older versions of Polymer. For 1.0, go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628050/how-to-style-a-paper-input-tag-in-polymer-1-0