# How to style a <paper-input> tag in Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer-1.0

How do you style the `<paper-input>` tag in Polymer 1.0

Can you show how to specifically custom style the label text color, the underline color, input text color, and how to access them using `custom-style`?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omASiF85JzI) video from the Polycasts series is an introduction to theming elements.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can change the appearance of `<paper-input>` by changing the custom properties listed over [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container#styling) (The information has been moved for the most recent version - it is available for versions older than v1.1.21).

Here's an example:

```
<style is="custom-style">
:root {
        /* Label and underline color when the input is not focused */
        --paper-input-container-color: red;

        /* Label and underline color when the input is focused */
        --paper-input-container-focus-color: blue;

        /* Label and underline color when the input is invalid */
        --paper-input-container-invalid-color: green;

        /* Input foreground color */
        --paper-input-container-input-color: black;
}
</style>
```

**EDIT:**

The `:root` selector is used to define [custom properties that apply to all custom elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-style). You can also target a specific element instead of `:root`:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-input-container.my-class {
        --paper-input-container-color: red;
        --paper-input-container-focus-color: blue;
        --paper-input-container-invalid-color: green;
        --paper-input-container-input-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Nice. This works well. What's the best practice around organizing this? Do you put this in a separate file and use an HTML import? Also, what does the `:root` signify? Can that be changed to something else? For example, associate it to a specific class or id? Thanks!

Comment: @ConAntonakos You can put this in a separate file. `:root` selector is used to define custom properties that apply to all custom elements. You can target a specific element, e.g., `paper-input.my-class { ... }`, instead of `root:`. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-style

Comment: Can you add a mixin to the examples?