# How to style the Paper Input to a normal input box?

Tags: polymer-1.0

Can anyone please help me to style the default  element to a normal input box? The default polymer  element is having an underline. I want to style it to a normal text box  (input box). I will be thankful if you are showing with a small example too.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: While I can't mark as a duplicate these questions get asked many times. You will need to use css variables and mixins. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628050/how-to-style-a-paper-input-tag-in-polymer-1-0?rq=1 (duplicate) and https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-properties (Polymer Styling docs)

Answer (score 0):

The [Paper Elements](https://beta.webcomponents.org/collection/PolymerElements/paper-ui-elements) are most useful when you are using [Material Design](https://material.google.com/). If you're not using Material Design but want the functionality of Paper Elements, then your best bet is to use [`iron-input`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-input) since that is intended to be used on a normal input box that you can apply your own styles to.

If you take a look at the [code for `paper-input`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.html), you'll see that [`iron-input`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-input) and [`iron-form-element-behavior`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form-element-behavior) are actually what gives it most of its functionality (there are some paper behaviors in there as well).